# How to create two different form for the customer registration one is default and the other is Seller

Tags: magento2, customer-address, customer-registration

I want to create the separate registration page for the seller and the customer, please guide me.

I created the custom module for the seller registration page, where i called the custom page in merchantregister_account_register.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::form/newregister.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setShowAddressFields">
            <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
        </action>
   </referenceBlock>
```

The phtml file is created in the /app/design/frontend/bs_complex/bs_complex3_child/Magento_Customer/templates/form/newregister.phtml (duplication of register.phtml)

while calling that module the error throws like the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please share what you tried so far? At least give try some

Comment: i created a custom module for the seller registration page where i called the phtml which is created in the magento_customer module. whenever i called my custom module url error throws like Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFrontendLabel() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ordamel2.3/app/code/Sss/Merchantregister/view/frontend/templates/register.phtml:69

Comment: Please post this comment at the question and give other information like create Block class, layout code for seller registration.